# CucumberJvm5SMFormatter not working after changing to open jdk 15.0.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, cucumber

i use Java with Cucumber in IntelliJ.

Today i installed JDK 15.0.1 and also updated IntelliJ to version 2022.3.3 (Community edition) and, afterwards, i cannot longer see my Tests Results with all the steps itemised as before:
[image: this was before]

now i only see:
[image]

In the scenario configuration, in Program Arguments i have this, as before:

```
--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm5SMFormatter --name "^Verify the shopping basket for multibooking for Listing with all variants allowed in one same location$”
```

but it does not seem to be working now.

Maybe CucumberJvm5SMFormatter plugin is not compatible with openJDK 15.0.1? or with IntelliJ 2022.3.3?
how can i check the compatibility myself?

BTW i have this in my pom.xml, in case it helps:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the "Show Passed" check mark:
[image]

See reference doc [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-and-exploring-test-results.html)